# Docker with Windows

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am new to Docker. I operate it on my Windows 10.
Started jenkins in interactive mode at `/bin/bash`, and i want to open the file `InitialAdminPassword` located at `/var/jenkins_home/secrets/`

How do i open this file?

`sudo` doesn't work, and using `apt-get` gives the error:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Also how do i find the location of my `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, why you need the location of the `Dockerfile`. This is a build-time thing, but I assume you downloaded the container from Docker Hub.

The [`jenkins` Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) drops privileges and executes as `jenkins` user, that's why you can't call `apt-get`.

On the one hand, this secret is emitted when starting the container:

```
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

114439956d184fe2b45e31c9333b9afb

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
```

When you attach to the container, you can display the file contents as follows:

```
$ docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
jenkins@<container_id>:/$ cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot! :)